# How to use coord_fixed with scale_x_continuous without losing the function of one or the other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot using scale_x_continuous(), scale_y_continuous(), and coord_fixed() and maybe coord_cartesian(). However one always seems to override the other one(s).

Consider the dataframe:

```
x<- as.vector(sample(250:500, 50))
y<- as.vector(sample(1:500, 50))
df<- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
```

I need to have the scale of the x and y axes set at a 1:1 ratio. This is easily accomplished like this:

```
p <-ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y))

p <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,500)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,500))
p <- p + coord_fixed()
p
```

Now I want to remove all of that empty space on the left side of the plot. The logical step to me would be to use coord_cartesian() to "zoom" into my plot with out changing it, but it does not work.

```
p <- p + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(250, 500), ylim = c(0,500)) 
p
```

This line of code does zoom me in, but now the effect of coord_fixed() is gone. (This is seen when you change the margins of the plot and the the ratio of the axis spacing changes as well).

I have tried many iterations of setting limits in all three of these functions, and removing and/or reordering these functions as well and they always seems to negate each other at one point. Even setting xlim and ylim within coord_fixed() itself stops it from working.

```
p <-ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x= x, y = y))

p <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,500)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,500))
p <- p + coord_fixed(ratio=1, xlim = c(250, 500), ylim = c(0,500))
p
```

How can I keep the ratio between my axes fixed at 1:1, while removing the empty space on the left of the plot?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need `coord_equal`? You might try `ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + coord_equal()`

Comment: Try changing the shape of the plot window

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Markus. I just played around with it a bit and it seems to behave the same (problematic) way as coord_fixed.

Comment: Can you add details explaining what your issue with coord_equal is. Because @markus suggestion does exactly what you requested "How can I keep the ratio between my axes fixed at 1:1, while removing the empty space on the left of the plot? "

Comment: @dww The issue with coord_equal is that the ratio on the axes is not 1:1 (you can see that the grid of the plot background is not square).

Comment: I don't see it either - taking just your original code and replacing the `scale_x_continuous` to `limits=c(250,500)` (while making sure that `coord_fixed()` comes *after* the `scale_x`), the result comes out fine as far as I can tell (note that the default image I'm getting gives minor grid lines on the x axis, making it look like rectangles rather than squares. Try adding `theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())`)

Comment: try `p + coord_fixed(ratio = diff(range(df$x)) / diff(range(df$y)), xlim=c(250, 500), ylim = c(0,500))`

Comment: or more precisely, `p + coord_fixed(ratio = 250/500, xlim=c(250, 500), ylim = c(0,500), expand = F)`

Comment: @dww that seems to do it, thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help -added it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coord_fixed`, and set the ratio to match the ratio between the limits of the two axes:

```
xlim = c(245, 505) 
ylim = c(-5,505)
p + coord_fixed(ratio = diff(xlim)/diff(ylim), xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, expand=F)
```

[image]